# Java - alternative to passing variables through many layers

Tags: java, interface

I'm building a small console application as an exercise in brushing up on Java (been doing Haskell and Scala for last year after a year of Java). I have the following interfaces modelling menu behaviour:

```
public interface MenuItem {
    public String output();
    public InputHandler requestInput();
```

And:

```
public interface InputHandler {
    public String promptUser();
    public MenuItem handleInput(String input);
}
```

With some sample implementations like so:

```
public class MainMenu implements MenuItem {

    public String output() {
        return "1.) Browse Books\n" +
               "2.) View membership details\n" +
               "3.) Exit\n";
    }

    public InputHandler requestInput() {
        return new InputHandler() {
            public String promptUser() {
                return "Please select an option:\n";
            }

            public MenuItem handleInput(String input) {
                int menuItem = Integer.parseInt(input);
                if (menuItem == 1) {
                    return new BrowseBooks();
                } else if (menuItem == 2) {
                    return new ViewUserDetails();
                } else {
                    return new MainMenu();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

My issue is that **SOME** of these MenuItem implementing classes (`BrowseBooksMenu` for example) require access to other classes (namely say a `LibraryManager` class that handles borrowing of books). I can't just pass this `LibraryManager` class into the `BrowseBooks` class because it would also need to be passed into the `MainMenu` class (because they are sort of circular), and thus become a big shitstorm of large constructors for instances that are only used in specific MenuItems.

What is a nice way to solve this?

Comment: you meant 'through many layers' in the title, right ?

Comment: Can't you create the LibraryManager as a singleton class? Also you could create a Listener for the LibraryManager... I am not sure if this is what you looking for, please let me know and I can give you more details.

Comment: Yep, Librarymanager can be a singleton. Not sure what you mean by a listener.

Comment: I posted a code example for you below, it's very generic but I think you can get the concept from that and adapt for what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into dependency injection as a solution. It's great for managing 
service dependencies in situations like this. There are a couple of good standalone DI implementations like [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), [Weld](http://www.seamframework.org/Weld) and [PicoContainer](http://picocontainer.codehaus.org/).

Comment: Good call, but I think it's overkill for a 200 line console app.

Comment: Throw together some singletons then. Two hundred lines ***is*** a very tiny app.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't just pass this `LibraryManager` class into the `BrowseBooks` class because it would also need to be passed into the `MainMenu` class (because they are sort of circular)

It depends on what is required to construct this `LibraryManager`. If nothing at all is required, you could simply construct that from within the `BrowseBooks` class. If some global config is required, you could construct a global singleton and store that in some static field. The answers on [Singleton Design Pattern in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8599956/1468366) have code snippets on how to initialize the singleton, depending on whether you want that initialization to occur early or lazily.

If you want to be flexible about where that manager comes from, you might want to have a look at [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), probably using some [Inversion of Control Container](http://java-source.net/open-source/containers).

Comment: Yeah, it does need global context (it's by definition quite stateful within itself), so I think using a static instance is easiest?

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra: Yes, looks that way. I included a link into my question where you can find useful code snippets for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it just by using design patterns, there is no need to use a DI system.

Here is a quick code prototype that I think will work for you, and remove the dependency between your LybraryManager and other classes.

```
//LybraryManager singleton class
        public class LybraryManager{

    public static LybraryManager getInstance(){    //basic code for singleton pattern }

    public void addLybraryManagerListener(LMListener listener){    listneres.add(listener) }

    public void someLybraryOperation(){
         //iterate by the listeners and invoke the method
         listener.someLybraryOperationExecuted(someParam); }


    public interface LMListener{
         public void someLybraryOperationExecuted(Object someParam);
    }

//Class MainMenu that implement listener for lybrarymanager, and listen to operation
public class MainMenu implements LMListner {
    public MainMenu(){
        LybraryManager.getInstance.addLMListener(this);
}

public void someLybraryOperationExecuted(Object someParam){
    //do anything you need
}

}
```

I hope it solves your problem :)